# bind a click event to from within a function that runs the same function

Tags: jquery

Basically I've created a sliding menu using jquery.

See code below...

```
menu_slide = function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if ( menuOpen == false ) {

        $('.pane').animate({
            'top' : $('#navigation ul').outerHeight() + 'px'
        }, 250 );
        menuOpen = true;

        $('#top').bind( "click", menu_slide ); 

    } else if ( menuOpen == true ) {

        $('#top').unbind("click");

        $('.pane').animate({
            'top' : 0 + 'px'
        }, 250 );
        menuOpen = false;

    }
}
```

Fired by this...

```
$("a.menu-button").on( "click", menu_slide );
```

Now when my menu opens, I would like to bind a click event to the the `div#top` so that div area acts as a button to close the menu. But the menu close I would like to remove it.

I thought my method of using...

```
$('#top').bind( "click", menu_slide );
```

Then removing it using...

```
$('#top').unbind("click");
```

would have the desired effect. But what happens is when I open the menu it just closes straight away.

And it's all because of this line... `$('#top').bind( "click", menu_slide );`

Can anyone advise on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with `$.one('click', function () { ... }`?

Comment: @bic you mean `$('#top').on( "click", menu_slide );` - yes it does exactly the same, but it does not make sense why it closing straight away

Comment: I meant `$.one()`. It's a special use case for binding a single execution handler. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like your `a.menu_button` elements are embedded inside your `div#top`:

```
<div id='top'>
    <a class='menu_button'></a>
    <a class='menu_button'></a>
    <a class='menu_button'></a>
</div>
```

If this is the case, then when you click on the menu_button, and bind a click event to top in the handler, the original menu_button click is propagating up, and subsequently triggering the `div#top` click event as well. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p66L8/).

In order to prevent this, you need to stop propagation of the `a.menu_button` click. You can do this by:

```
return false; // stops propagation AND prevents default
```

or

```
e.stopPropagation(); // stops propagation
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p66L8/1/)

Note, my demo makes use of `$.one()` to bind to the top div. This method binds a handler to the event that will only execute one time, and then automatically will unbind itself afterwards. This is handy for when you want to handle a single event, and don't want to have to worry about unbinding it manually.

Comment: Works like magic. Indeed you we're right I was just making a fiddle to replicate my issue. Thank you so much indeed for pointing this out and explaining. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to bind the event when the menu is opened? Can `$('#top')` be clicked when the menu is closed?

I think you would be better off just binding them both right from the start

```
$('a.menu-button, #top').click(menu_slide);
```

And then get rid of the `$.bind()` and `$.unbind()` calls.

Since you are already checking a variable to see if the menu is opened or closed, clicking either one should function correctly, and I'm assuming the `#top` element is hidden when the menu is closed.